# creation 2D grid in CUDA for GPGPU using C++

Tags: cuda

I am trying to extend my grid from a 1d to a 2d grid. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my current code:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
```

In the `#include` list I have these definitions:

```
#define BLOCKS_PER_GRID 102

#define THREADS_PER_BLOCK 1024
```

Comment: See [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy)

Comment: please provide some additional information about the size and type of your input data, and the nature of your problem. Posting some code would be better.

Comment: my data type Float, data size 102540 bytes . about problem iam trying to increase the ability of kernel to execute more functions

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want 1024 threads per block, the block can be easily reshaped to 2D.

`32 x 32 = 1024;`

So your block will look like this:

```
dim3 Block(32,32); //1024 threads per block. Will only work for devices of at least 2.0 Compute Capability.
```

I don't know what is your exact requirement, but usually number of blocks is not fixed (as you have defined in the macro). The number of blocks depend on the input data size, so that the grid scales dynamically.

Going with you case, you have many options, but the nearest optimal size for your grid comes out to be `17 x 6` or `6 x 17`.

```
dim3 Grid(17,6);
```

Now you can call the kernel with these parameters:

```
kernel<<<Grid,Block>>>();
```

Inside the kernel, the 2-Dimensional index of the thread is calculated as follows:

```
int xIndex = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int yIndex = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
```

Or if you follow the Row/Column convention instead of x/y, then:

```
int row    = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int column = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

Comment: i tried this solution but doesnt work. i am trying to use 2D grid to increase the ability of the kernel to execute more functions

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a 2D grid of 1-dimensional threadblocks, in order to get around the limitation of 65535 blocks per grid dimension (for pre-cc3.0 devices).  This may be an easier way of extending a fundamentally 1-D problem past the limit without introducing a 2-D array representation for the data.

Let's assume we have a `DATA_ELEMENTS` parameter defined to be the number of elements (one element per thread) that your kernel will work on.  If `DATA_ELEMENTS` is larger than 65535*1024, then you cannot handle them all using a 1-D grid, if each thread handles only 1 element.

you can leave your `THREADS_PER_BLOCK` parameter the same.  Your thread index calculation inside the kernel will change to something like:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * ((gridDim.x * blockIdx.y) + blockIdx.x));
```

you will want to be sure to condition your kernel calculations with something like:

```
if (idx < DATA_ELEMENTS){
   (kernel code)
  }
```

Your grid dimensions will be as follows:

```
dim3 grid;
if (DATA_ELEMENTS > (65535*THREADS_PER_BLOCK)){ // create a 2-D grid
  int gridx = 65535;  // could choose another number here
  int gridy = ((DATA_ELEMENTS+(THREADS_PER_BLOCK-1))/THREADS_PER_BLOCK)/gridx;
  if ((((DATA_ELEMENTS+(THREADS_PER_BLOCK-1))/THREADS_PER_BLOCK)%gridx) != 0) gridy++;
  grid.x=gridx;
  grid.y=gridy;
  grid.z=1;
  }
else{ // create a 1-D grid
  int gridx = (DATA_ELEMENTS+(THREADS_PER_BLOCK-1))/THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
  grid.x=gridx;
  grid.y=1;
  grid.z=1;
  }
```

and you would launch your kernel as:

```
 kernel<<<grid, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(...);
```

Another method to tackle this kind of problem is to create a 1-D grid of some dimension (let's say the total number of threads in the grid is `NUM_THREADS_PER_GRID`), and have each thread work on more than one element in the array of data elements, using something like a for-loop or while-loop:

```
while (idx < DATA_ELEMENTS) {
    (code to process an element)
    idx += NUM_THREADS_PER_GRID
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Robert's solutions above. The only comment I have about his first solution is that it seems that one should make `gridx` as small as one can when `DATA_ELEMENTS > (65535*THREADS_PER_BLOCK)`. The reason is that if the number of data elements is `65535*THREADS_PER_BLOCK + 1`, and `gridx` is `65535`, then `65535*2*THREADS_PER_BLOCK` are launched, so almost half of the threads will do nothing. If `gridx` is smaller, then there will be less threads that do nothing.