# cuda grid 2-Dimension Thread Identifier

Tags: cuda

hy, i have 2Dimendions Grid and 1Dimensions block:

```
dim3 dimGrid(K,N);

dim3 dimBlock(F);
```

How can i calculate the unique thread identifier? 
thanks

EDIT:
sorry, the dimBlock is not K. F different K different N

Answer (score 3):

The local thread Id:

```
unsigned ltid = threadIdx.x; // Varies from 0 to K-1
```

The number of blocks can be calculated by:

```
unsigned num_blocks = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
```

The number of threads before the current block:

```
unsigned boff = num_blocks * blockDim.x; // Multiples of K * N * K
```

Adding the current thread Id to the number of threads before the current block, you can get the global unique id.

```
unsigned gtid = ltid + boff;
```

**EDIT**

Modified the answer. The original was written under the wrong assumptions.

Comment: I'm not sure this is complete.  For one thing, threadIdx.y is always 1 for a 1D threadblock.

Answer (score 2):

Purely for the sake of clarity (the other answers are correct as well, but I find this approach more conducive to learning), the global index of any given thread for 2D blocks and grids can be found via:

```
int index_x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;    
int index_y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int grid_width = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
//get the global index 
int global_idx = index_y * grid_width + index_x;
```

This may be useful for if you ever introduce a second dimension for your block size, as it'll handle that case automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation I would use would be something like this:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * ((gridDim.x * blockIdx.y) + blockIdx.x));
```

You may also be interested in the answer I posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100723/creation-2d-grid-in-cuda-for-gpgpu-using-c/14327364#14327364).